# open file in command line tool app xcode objective c

Tags: xcode

I would like to read a simple text file in objective-C (command line tool) this is my code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {

    // insert code here...
    NSLog(@"Hello, World!");


    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *aPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"txt"];




    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:aPath];

    if (fileExists) {
        NSLog(@"THERE!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"NOT THERE!");
    }
```

but I tried full path like `/Users/Me/dat`a or added `data.txt` into xcode but it just won't load the file, what am I missing? thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Command-line tools don't have a bundle associated with them. You'll have to store the file somewhere else (a directory in `/Library/Application Support`, for example, or perhaps somewhere in `/usr/local/share` if you're installing the tool to `/usr/local`) and read it from there.